# Is there an abstract pattern I can use to web scrape journal abstracts in rvest?

Tags: r, rvest

I am new to web scraping so please forgive me if what I am looking for is not possible. I want to extract all the journal article abstracts from a large database.

I am able to generate all the links from the database.

```
pangiaoDB <- read_html('https://panglaodb.se/papers.html')
table <- pangiaoDB %>% 
 html_node(xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table') %>% 
 html_table()
url <- lapply(table$DOI, function(x) {
    paste('https://doi.org/', x, sep = '')
})
head(url)
```

The table has over 800 unique journals.

```
length(unique(table$Journal))
length(table$Journal)
```

The abstracts are tucked away in various ways but for the most part I have found them in
`xpath = '//*[@id="3179475"]/section')` and `xpath = '//*[@id="Abs1"]`. The ladder is less of an issue but how can I generate a relative xpath for abstracts in the former path?

Comment: If you have a doi for each paper, you can use e.g. `rcrossref::cr_abstract` to get abstracts based on those dois.

Comment: E.g. `library(rcrossref); library(purrr); abstracts <- map(table$DOI, possibly(cr_abstract, otherwise = NA))`

Comment: There are a lot more distinct DOI than distinct journals. Will you be expecting to retrieve all 4,567 (currently) ? Sounds like Axeman's answer could be any easy solution.

Comment: @Axeman your advice answered my question

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I ended up using after getting feedback from @Axeman:

```
data <- rcrossref::cr_abstract(str_remove(url, pattern = 'https://doi.org/')) %>%
                          str_remove(., pattern = 'Abstract')
```